# VBA - Creating a new sheet and inserting data

Tags: vba, excel

I asked a question yesterday that was solved, however, my code only works for two sheets.  I am having an issue with pasting my data into a newly created sheet.  My code will create a second sheet and paste the data into into it.  However, when I try for a third sheet, it creates the sheet, but inserts the data into the second sheet.  Here is my code:

```
Sub ImportData()

    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook   As Workbook
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant

    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel 2007, *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa", Title:="Select File To Import")
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    Call ReadDataFromSourceFile(fNameAndPath)


    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = Nothing
    Set wkbSourceBook = Nothing

End Sub


Sub ReadDataFromSourceFile(filePath As Variant)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim src As Workbook
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(filePath, False, False)

    ' COPY DATA FROM SOURCE (CLOSE WORKGROUP) TO THE DESTINATION WORKBOOK.
    ' GET THE TOTAL ROWS FROM THE SOURCE WORKBOOK.
    Dim srcRng As Range   ' last line from source
    With src.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set srcRng = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook
        If .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("A1") = "" Then
            .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count).Value = srcRng.Value
        Else:
            .Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count).Value = srcRng.Value
        End If
    End With

    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    src.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set src = Nothing

End Sub
```

So, in short, My code works for the first sheet, when I select the first file and for the second file.  However, when I go to insert the third file into the third sheet, it creates a new sheet and places the data in "Sheet2" instead of the newly created sheet.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you tried debug your code step by step?

Comment: @DavidG. - Yes, But I am unsure of the exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by denoting `Sheets.Count` as an integer.

```
Dim n as Double
Dim wksNew as Excel.Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        If .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("A1") = "" Then
            .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count).Value = srcRng.Value
        Else:
            Set wksNew = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Sheets.Count))
            n = .Sheets.Count
            .Worksheets(n).Range("A1").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count).Value = srcRng.Value
        End If
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change it like so, does it work? The change explicitly declares the worksheet to be worked on. I can't say that I know why the Count function gives you an incorrect value.

```
Dim wksNew as Excel.Worksheet    
...    

With ThisWorkbook
    If .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("A1") = "" Then
        .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count).Value = srcRng.Value
    Else:
        Set wksNew = .Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        wksNew.Range("A1").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count).Value = srcRng.Value
    End If
End With
```

Comment: That didn't work, it didn't even work for the second sheet. I had to change the line you changed to `Set wksNew = .Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count))`

Comment: That makes sense, I forgot about adding the parentheses with the "set" statement. Did it still not work after the parentheses? If not, you might add a period between = and Worksheets and put a period before Sheets. I have had problems with that in the past, but it is inconsistent and depends greatly on the context.

`wksNew = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Sheets.Count))`

Comment: It did not work still, yes.  The `.Worksheets` is need because it is a with statement